# Polynomial root labeling tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to label the roots of the polynomial below:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2,thick]
\draw[->](-3mm,0mm)--(36mm,0mm) node at (34mm,-2.4mm){$p$};
%       \draw[shift={(+0.5,0)}] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below] {$\bar{p}$}
\draw[->](0mm,-3mm)--(0mm,14mm) node[above] {$\beta  p^2-p (\beta +\kappa \sigma     +1)+1$};
\draw[domain=-0.05:2] plot(\x,{((\x-0.5))*(\x-1.2)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

Any help is appreciated. The shift method doesnt seem to compile.

Comment: Add `;` end of the line.

Comment: Please post a minimal working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As  ferahfeza commented you were missing the trailing `;` in your attempt to manually label the intersection:

[image]

`Tikz` is really a drawing package. For graphing you really should use `pgfplots` which was specifically designed for this purpose:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2,thick]
\draw[->](-3mm,0mm)--(36mm,0mm) node at (34mm,-2.4mm){$p$};
       \draw[shift={(+0.5,0)},red] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below] {$\bar{p}$};
\draw[->](0mm,-3mm)--(0mm,14mm) node[above] {$\beta  p^2-p (\beta +\kappa \sigma     +1)+1$};
\draw[domain=-0.05:2] plot(\x,{((\x-0.5))*(\x-1.2)});
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    clip=false,
    ylabel={$\beta  p^2-p (\beta +\kappa \sigma +1)+1$},
    xlabel=$p$,
    axis lines=middle,
    xticklabels={},% if you don't want x tick labels
    yticklabels={},% if you don't want y tick labels
    xtick=\empty,% if you don't want x ticks
    ytick=\empty,% if you don't want y ticks
    extra x ticks={0.5,1.2},
    extra x tick labels={$\color{red}\bar{p}$,1.2},
    extra tick style={major tick length=5pt, tick style={red, line width=0.1em}},
    ]

    \addplot[domain=-0.05:2, samples=100, blue, ultra thick] plot(\x,{((\x-0.5))*(\x-1.2)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Look up the intesections library in the tikz manual.

[image: intersection]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2,thick]
\draw[->,name path=zero](-3mm,0mm)--(36mm,0mm) node at (34mm,-2.4mm){$p$};
%       \draw[shift={(+0.5,0)}] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below] {$\bar{p}$}
\draw[->](0mm,-3mm)--(0mm,14mm) node[above] {$\beta  p^2-p (\beta +\kappa \sigma     +1)+1$};
\draw[domain=-0.05:2,name path=poly] plot(\x,{((\x-0.5))*(\x-1.2)});
\fill [red, opacity=0.5, name intersections={of=poly and zero}]
(intersection-1) circle (2pt) node {1}
(intersection-2) circle (2pt) node {2};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```